# How to detect new dApp deployed?

Tags: solana-program, dapp

I wanna know to listen to the new dApp deployed on Solana automation. Do anyone here know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what you're asking? You can subscribe to account changes using the websocket https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#accountsubscribe and get a notification anytime a program is updated, or you can try to subscribe to all notifications from the loader program `BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111` using https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#programsubscribe